# F#: Apply a value as though it is a function

Tags: function, functional-programming, f#

Is it possible in F# to apply a value as though it is a function? For example:

```
let record =
    {|
        Func = fun x -> x * x
        Message = "hello"
    |}
let message = record.Message   // unsweetened field access
let unsweet = record.Func 3    // unsweetened function application
let sweet = record 3           // sweetened function application
```

Right now, the last line doesn't compile, of course:

```
error FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied.
```

Is there some sort of syntactical sweetener that would allow me to "route" function application as I see fit, while still retaining its normal unsweetened behavior as well? I'm thinking of something magic like this:

```
// magically apply a record as though it was a function
let () record arg =
    record.Func arg
```

(Note: I used a record in this example, but I'd be happy with a class as well.)

Comment: I think you are looking for an *implicit operator* such as you can define in C# (and is used there to transparently call methods defined by ``Func`` and ``Action`` instances). F# made the conscious decision to not use them, so what you are looking for will not be possible.

Comment: You can actually create a class that inherits from `FSharpFunc<a, b>` and implements its own `Invoke()`; but even then, it needs to be explicitly upcast to `obj` and re-downcast to `a -> b` in order to call it like a normal function. So I don't think it's possible to do it as lightly as you would like.

Comment: Thanks for both comments. I think you're right.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I can think of would be a custom operator using statically resolved type parameters to resolve a specific property of type `FSharpFunc`, then invoke the function with the supplied input parameter.  Something like this:

```
let record =
    {|
        Func = fun x -> x * x
        Message = "hello"
    |}

let inline (>.>) (r: ^a) v = 
    let f = (^a : (member Func: FSharpFunc< ^b, ^c>) r)    
    f v

record >.> 3 // val it : int = 9
```

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. This would work, except that I'm hoping to mix normal and "magic" function application (i.e. currying): `makeRecord "hello" 3` would create a record and then apply it to the value 3.